# fwrite not behaving as it should be

Tags: c, binary, fwrite

I have a C program that writes to a file using fwrite(..) and the result is not consistent with the function's arguments I provide.

```
  uint32_t x = 1009716161;
  FILE * file = fopen("helloop.txt", "wb+");
  rewind(file);
  fwrite( &x, sizeof(uint32_t), 1, file);
  fclose(file);
```

When I check the file afterward it seems to contains symbols that does not translate into anything

```
>cat helloop.txt
>Á/<
```

as I should be getting this

```
>cat helloop.txt
>000000003C2F0BC1
```

I checked the file's permissions and I chmodded it

```
 chmod 777 helloop.txt
```

The way I see it I have a 1 element of size 32 bit integer that I want to write to file, 
what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: The file's permissions are irrelevant. Setting the permissions to 777 makes no sense. A file should not have execute permission unless it's actually needed, and it very rarely makes sense for a file to be writable by every user on the system.

Answer (score 2):

Your program did exactly what you told it to.

In general, if a program you've written seems to be misbehaving, you shouldn't jump to the conclusion that the operating system, the compiler, or the runtime library is at fault. It's far more likely that there's a bug in your program, or that you've misunderstood something. That remains true no matter how many years of experience you have.

The value `1009716161`, expressed in hexadecimal, is `0x3c2f0bc1`. When you write that value to a binary file, you write 4 8-bit bytes, with values `0x3c`, `0x2f`, `0x0b`, and `0xc1`. In ASCII, those are `'<'`, `'/'`, and two characters outside the printable ASCII range. The order in which they're written depends on the endianness your system, but the contents you report seem consistent with that.

I"m not sure why you'd expect to see `000000003C2F0BC1`. That's 16 byte when you only wrote 4 bytes to the file. Furthermore, binary files do not contain an ASCII rendering of the hexadecimal representation of the data you wrote -- they just contain the data.

If you examine the file by converting it from raw binary to hexadecimal (by using the `hexdump` or `od -x` command if your system has it), you should see something recognizable.

And if you open the file in binary mode and use `fread` to read the data back into a `uint32_t` object, you should get the original value `1009716161` back -- which is the whole point.

Answer (score 0):

> cat helloop.txt
>   Á/<

`cat` prints character data. It doesn't print a 4-byte value in a file as a 32-bit integer.

> as I should be getting this
>
> cat helloop.txt
>   000000003C2F0BC1

No you shouldn't, not with `cat`. You'd have to write the character string "000000003C2F0BC1" to the file if you expect to get that. The file would probably be 16 characters long. I'd bet right now if you run `ls -l helloop.txt` you'll see size `4` because you wrote a uint32_t binary integer to the file.

> what am I doing wrong ?

As far as I can tell, the only thing you've done wrong is expecting `cat` to print out your uint32_t as a hexadecimal representation. (Though I did not check your hex value, so that may be incorrect as well)

See if you have `hexdump` on your Linux machine, it may give you better results.

EDIT: If you actually DO want to print a uint32_t as a hex string, you can use `fprintf(..., "%x", x)` with the `x` or `X` format specifier, but keep in mind this is not compatible with fwrite/fread, so to read it back in you'll have to read in the string and convert back from hex to int.

Comment: There you go. :) So your program worked. You just had the wrong expectation of `cat`